# Send Sms android with font type

Tags: android, android-activity, fonts

Is it possible to send sms in android with defined font type when user open he gets text in particular font.
According to my search it is possible by usign utf coding

```
string text = "\u24D7\u24D4\u24D8\u24D8\u24DB World"; 
editText.setText(text );
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                 intent.setType("text/plain");
                 intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT",  text );
                 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

But it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

sorry not possible,Because android does't provide any of function to send text with font type to third party Application.